# Почему приходит пустой запрос?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Делаю пост запрос:

```
            headers = {
'content-type': "application/json",
'cache-control': "no-cache",
}
        res = requests.request("POST", COCONUT_SEND_REQUEST, data=payload, headers=headers)
        print (res.text)
```

Но приходит запрос без тела, запрос приходит на сайт php laravel. В чем может быть причина? через postman все работает

Comment: А зачем объявлен `headers`?

Comment: @МихаилМуругов забыл дописать, но все равно не работает

Comment: Что значит *приходит запрос без тела*? Запросы отправляются, приходят ответы.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, Я отправляю запросы, где в body есть инфа, но когда я на сервере смотрю запрос, он пустой